# Element not clickable at a certain point

Tags: angular, selenium, automation, robotframework

Hi I am trying to click an element but not able to do so.
I am getting the below error message:

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1303, 86). Other element would receive the click: ...
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)

[image]

Comment: try to put some explicit wait before click

Comment: Please post some code example. What is the element you are trying to click? Is it part of some responsive element with slide in animations or something? Have you tried using waits?

Comment: Added the image in the post, I am trying to click sign out, I tried it with by adding wait, also tried clicking parent class.

Comment: @user380696    welcome to SO!, Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly, adding image of html code is bad practice no onw will write that code for you by looking at image, please add html as code in the post, also provide your code trials , errors you facing, what is expected?, what is actually happening?, sample data if any etc needed in good questions to receive good amount of response, its kind of help to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is because other element is disturbing while you try to click.

Solution: Try explicit wait, with condition when webelement is displayed in DOM, click it.